# Licensing: What is the license for LibFindMacros.cmake

Tags: cmake

I was wondering if anyone knows the license for LibFindMacros.cmake linked to from http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries.  I can't find anywhere where it says it & it makes it so much easier when writing new find_package modules that aren't included with CMake.

Answer (score 7):

It was originally written by me, and you may consider it Public Domain.

Answer (score 1):

As it's been posted to the wiki and the wiki states that content is available under the Creative Commons, then that code is available to you under the creative commons license. (If the code isn't available under that license, the moderators would be obligated to remove it.)

From the bottom of the site:
Content is available under Attribution 2.5.